# ZendFramework Noob: Adding text on top of a form

Tags: zend-framework

I've just (as in today) started working on some ZF stuff.

I have a Form that needs to have some text in a div appear at the top of the form, but I have no idea how to include it.

The structure of the form is:

```
class MyForm extends \app\forms\FormType {
    public function init() {
        // gets all the form elements of the parent
        parent::init();

        // A few additional form elements for MyForm created here

    }
}
```

Any help would be apprecaited!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller where you instantiate the form object just set it with the view object like this:

```
public function actionNameAction()
{
    // ...
    if (/* some condition to check form page */) {
        $this->view->divText = 'your text';
    }
}
```

Then put the div in the action-name.phtml script:

```
views/scripts/controller/action-name.phtml
```

Contents:

```
<?php if (!empty($this->divText)): ?>
    <div><?php echo $this->divText; ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Additionally, you could pass the view object by reference to your form class. Just overload the construct function like so:

```
public function __construct($options = null, &$view)
{
    parent::__construct($options);
    $this->view = $view;
}
```

Then in your controller when you instantiate your form object do this:

```
$form = new MyForm(null, $this->view);
```

Let's go back to your form class once again and modify the init() method:

```
public function init()
{
    // ...
    $this->view->divText = 'Text set from within ' . __CLASS__;
}
```

Using this way, you won't have to put any conditional if statements checking anything in the controller.  You're *already* checking if `$this->divText` is not empty in the view, so by passing the view object to your form class you can ensure that that text will only be set when the form is being used.

Comment: The problem with this is that multiple forms use the action and that phtml to render, but I just need the text on one of the forms. If I do it that way the text shows up on all the forms.

Comment: right, gotcha. well I made some edits that should accommodate your issue.